# Objective-CでJSONの取得がうまくいかない

Tags: php, objective-c, json

phpでJSON形式のデータを吐き出すプログラムをつくりました。
これをObjective-Cから取得しようと思っているのですが、うまくいきません。
URLの部分を、東京電力電力供給状況API(http://tepco-usage-api.appspot.com/latest.json)に変更すると、正常に取得できているようですが、自作のJSONデータではnullが返ってきます。
　ウェブ方面にお詳しい方、ご教授願います。

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://kokun.sakura.ne.jp/tutor/JSONTest.php";
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSData *json = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

【追記】
以下はJSON形式のデータを吐き出すphpプログラムの全文です。

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JSONTest</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$array = array(
    "name" => "shou",
    "date" => "2015-06-14 19:53:00",
    "content" => "hello world",
);
$json = json_encode($array);
echo $json;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: どこで`nil`になっているのか、ダウンロードに失敗して`nil`なのか、JSONデータを解析する段階で`nil`になるのか。その分析は、質問者さんの責任の範囲だと思いますが、いかがですか？

Comment: JSONTest.phpにアクセスしてソースを見れば分かりますが、JSONじゃなくてHTMLになっていますよ。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
phpから.json形式のファイルを生成するプログラムをつくればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: ファイルを生成するというか、直接JSON形式でレスポンスを返せばOKです。phpのコードも貼り付けたほうが良いと思います。

Comment: 「php json 作成」や「php json 生成」などで調べていますが、上記の例と同じようにhtml上にjsonを吐き出すサンプルしか見つかっていない状況です。
すみません、私の知識不足のために適当な検索ワードも思いつきません。
直接JSON形式でレスポンスを返す、というのはどのような関数を使えばよいでしょうか？

Comment: 一部ではなくJSONTest.phpの中身を全部書いてください。

Comment: 了解しました。修正いたしました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSONTest.phpの中のHTMLコードは不要なので全部消してください。
phpファイルの中身はこれだけでOKです。

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "name" => "shou",
    "date" => "2015-06-14 19:53:00",
    "content" => "hello world",
);

$json = json_encode($array);
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo $json;
```

Comment: 正常に動作しました。
丁寧に解答に導いてくださりありがとうございました。
大変助かりました！